# Как сделать сервис статистики посещений для сторонних сайтов?

Tags: php

Идея проста - создать сайт, который бы предоставлял возможность другим веб-ресурсам при установке скрипта подсчитывать количество посещений за день.

Информация о посещении хранилась бы в таблице MySQL на моём сервере:

код записи | код сайта | дата посещения | айпи-адрес посетителя

Сложности:

1. Во-первых, не знаю как сделать так чтобы, инф-ция с сайта, на котором установлен счётчик, стекалась в мою БД. На своём сайте всё понятно, делаешь запрос на добавление инфы, а вот как сделать реализацию запроса с другого сервера понятия не имею.
2. Во-вторых, не знаю как сделать запрос, отражающий кол-во посещений на стороннем сайте из моей БД и выгрузить инф-цию в виде счётчика на сайте-клиенте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать!..

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых, ваша идея далеко не нова. Во-вторых, делается это при помощи картинки, на стороннем ресурсе размещается тэг [image] со ссылкой на ваш сайт статистики, ссылка эта указывает, например, на php скрипт, который собирает нужную инфу(IP-адрес, Referer), заносит ее в вашу БД, а затем рисует картинку с посещаемостью сайта, на котором размещена картинка, и отдает ее посетителю. Эта самая простая схема, более того на нее не повлияет отключение JavaScript'a.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. идея не нова. Меня просто интересует механизм обмена информацией между моим и сторонним сайтом. Я же не могу посылать запрос с сайта-клиента на изменение / чтение БД. Сервер блокирует сторонние запросы.

Comment: Я вам описал схему, по которой работают ресурсы подобные вашему. Если обладатель сайта, на котором размещается ваша картинка, не хочет ее вставлять (например, она не вписывается в дизайн), то можно использовать однопиксельную прозрачную png-картинку. По поводу запроса, браузер наткнувшись на тэг <img> ссылающийся на ваш сайт, сам отправит на него GET запрос, из которого вы и вытащите IP-адрес и название сайта, на котором располагается ваша картинка (Referer).

Comment: Так же стоит в адрес картинки передать параметр id сайта, на котором она установлена, а в php-скрипте на вашем сайте, если браузер не передал referer, то ориентироваться по этому параметру.

Comment: то есть на стороннем сайте должен быть код типа:
<a href=www.mysite.ru/script.php?id=n><img screen='www.mysite.ru/pict.jpg'></a>

Comment: нет, вставляться будет только тэг <img src="www.mysite.ru/script.php?id=n"/>, а сам скрипт (script.php) либо перенаправит запрос на www.mysite.ru/pict.jpg, либо сам отдаст картинку (например, при помощи функции readfile).

Comment: блин, не могу пока давать ответы на коммент, так что строчу тут:

> сам отправит на него GET запрос, из
> которого вы и вытащите IP-адрес и
> название сайта(Referer)

хочу добавить уточнение, что реферал можно подменить отправив запрос сокетом и указав в заголовках левое имя сайта, а это уже черевато накруткой счетчика

Comment: скажем так, любой из запросов можно симулировать через сокеты и ничто от этого не защитит, в том числе и JavaSctipt.

Answer (score 0):

Есть много разных способов, например <script src="http://mysite.com/counter.php?mode=add"></script>
Здесь документ пытается загрузить файл counter.php, можно с параметрами. Изучайте PHP и основы JS.